# Creating an arbitrarily large "fake" file

Tags: files, sparse-files

I would like to create a special file similar to `/dev/null` or `/dev/random`, where the file doesn't actually exist but you can read from it all the same, except that I could actually set a cap on the apparent size of the file.

To put it another way, I want to create a special file where (assuming I set the cap at 500GB) when I "cat" the file it will output all 500GB of the file and then stop. It needs to act the same as an actual 500GB file, but without taking the space. The contents of this file don't matter, it could be all `\0`'s like `/dev/null`, or just a small string being sent over and over, or whatever.

Is this something that's do-able? The only thing remotely close I've been able to find is man pages talking about `mknod`, but those weren't very helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create a [**sparse file**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) on certain filesystems, which will *appear* to be a certain size, but won't actually use that much space *on disk*.

```
$ dd if=/dev/null of=sparse bs=1024 count=1 seek=524288000
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 2.4444e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
$ ls -l sparse 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ignacio ignacio 536870912000 May  9 22:25 sparse
$ du -h sparse
0   sparse
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Best case I was hoping for a solution where I could actually script out what the output is (like, for every seek position you look at the data there would be a hash of that position or something along those lines), but that was pretty out there. This definitely works for now, thanks!

Comment: @MediocreGopher, you certainly could do something like that with [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm looking for a similar solution, but I need it to be able to confuse `du` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the portable dd/seek based solution already mentioned some Unixes have specialized commands:

At least on [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/mkfile-1m.html), [MacOS/X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mkfile.8.html) and [Irix](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/tpl/cgi-bin/getdoc.cgi?coll=0650&db=man&fname=/usr/share/catman/a_man/cat1/mkfile.z):

```
mkfile -n 500m sparseFile
```

On HP-UX [prealloc](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02263435/c02263435.pdf), on AIX lmktemp. and many Linux distributions have [truncate](http://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to seek back in the file, you could use a named pipe:

```
mkfifo my_special_file
yes | head -n 100 > my_special_file&
cat my_special_file
```

Of course, you can use any other command, including a complex script, to generate data in the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with dd, you can specify a blocksize and a count, and thereby limit the size like this:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=5 bs=1024 > nullfile
```

If you want to read from it, just pipe it:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom count=5 bs=1024 | yourReadingProcess
```

In former times, every linux installation I made came with some networking tools, portmap, inet.d and such, and in inet.d, there where some services always specified, one of them was described/named chargen, if I remember correctly.

(... one minute later ...)

Yes. In /etc/services, you find

```
chargen         19/tcp          ttytst source
chargen         19/udp          ttytst source
```

So I guess it is a service to test something, and which sends chars - maybe random - over the network. I only find /etc/xinet.d/chargen on my PC. There are more infos:

```
# default: off
# description: An xinetd internal service which generate characters.  The
# xinetd internal service which continuously generates characters until the
# connection is dropped.  The characters look something like this:
# !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefg
# This is the tcp version.
```

However, I don't know how to use it for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the truncate command.
Ex: The following will create a 5MB file.

```
truncate -s 5M 5.dumpfile
```